# Uncaught ReferenceError js

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have JS code and I have little problem with that 
in my code, I have ridiculous problem but I can't find it please help me

it's my Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: lD0MnvK211576600138 is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

my code is = lD0MnvK211576600138

```
<li><a onclick="recived( {{$item->code}} )">done</a></li>
```

js:

```
<script>
    function recived(code) {
        console.log(code);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/incomingCargo',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: {
                'code':code
            }, // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log('g')
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `{{$item->code}}`?  Is that some kind of template?  PHP?

Comment: yes its for laravel blade and return a value

Comment: May you show an example of the html that gets generated by laravel?

Comment: {{$item->code}} retturn this value : lD0MnvK211576600138 
 and in html it look like this :
<li><a onclick="lD0MnvK211576600138">done</a></li>

Comment: $item is an object

Comment: Can you try this one: <li><a onclick="recived( '{{$item->code}}' )">done</a></li>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to surround `{{$item->code}}` in single quotes.  You're inserting a string into your JS code, but strings need to be enclosed in quotes:

```
        ↓               ↓    
recived('{{$item->code}}')
```